# Creating a query using loop for the WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a MySQL query using a loop for the where clause. I have a solution, but I feel like there should be a better solution. My code is as follows

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `t1` WHERE';
$names = ['John','Steve','Robert'];

foreach($names as $name){
    $query .= " `name` = '$name` OR";
}

echo $query;
```

In this case query ends with "OR" that makes it invalid. The solution I have is to trim it using

```
echo rtrim($query," OR");
```

I feel like there should be a cleaner way of doing it. Any suggestions?

Comment: there's several approaches. one way would have the static part of the SQL as `... WHERE 1=0` and then repeatedly append `OR name = 'foo'` (with leading space). Beware of incorporating potentially unsafe values into the SQL text, and opening SQL Injection vulnerability. In this case, we have a static array, so there's no risk. In the more general case, where we don't know that the contents of the array are "safe" for including into SQL, we would use prepared statement with bind placeholders, or barring that, properly escape the values ala mysql_real_escape_string C function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix your query using `where in` and [`join`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.join.php). In your case it should be :

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `t1` WHERE name IN (\'' . join($names,'\',\'') . '\')';
```

Note: join is aliases for implode. It help code readability. Be careful with SQL Injection. You might want to validate the input or using PDO.

Comment: I liked the way you added `'` around each name

Answer (score 1):

You could push the tests to an array and then implode them with `OR`:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `t1` WHERE';
$names = ['John','Steve','Robert'];

$tests = array();
foreach($names as $name){
    $tests[] = "`name` = '$name'";
}
$query .= implode(' OR ', $tests);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/UAr91)

Answer (score 1):

I do what you do in my applications, just becareful with more complicated `WHERE` clauses in the future.

For example, if your array is empty, you should omit "WHERE"

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `t1`';
if ($names) $query .= " WHERE";
```

if your where clause will have `AND` you should give attention to that `AND` is having higher precedence than `OR` and to use the proper brackets  `()`

In the code example you provided you can also do this to avoid `rtrim`

```
$names = ['John','Steve','Robert'];
foreach ($names as &$name) $name = "'$name'";
unset($name);
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `t1` WHERE `name` IN (' . implode(', ', $names) . ') ';
```